# Scala Read API Full Response

Tags: scala

I am working with a paginated API and would like to read the Json for each page dynamically. I have implemented this using a while loop and would like to break out of it when I have read the last page's Json

```
var pageNumber = 1
val pageSize = 1000
while (pageNumber >= 1) {
  println("Inside the while loop!" + pageNumber)
  url = url.concat("OWNER_MI_KEY&dataset_version=v1.1&pageNumber=$pageNumber&pageSize=$pageSize")
  val apiResponse = MakePostHttpRestCalls(url) // makes request to external rest endpoint
 if (apiResponse != ""){
    println("Got api response")
    println("apiResponse :" + apiResponse)
    val apiJson = parseApiResponse(apiResponse)//parses the json response
    println("apiJson :" + apiJson)
    if (apiJson.length == 0){
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this in my code?

Comment: Use a boolean switch to break the loop when you found the last page.

Comment: Put an `else { pageNumber = 0 }` after your `if(apiJson.length == 0)`

Comment: `while` is inherently not functional, so better to use a recursive function to avoid the `var` and make the exit condition clearer (it is the code path without the recursive call)

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, here is a rough idea of how this might look as a recursive function, which is the functional way of doing this kind of thing that Scala is designed for.

```
def readResponsePages(pageSize: Int) = {
  def loop(pageNumber: Int, responses: List[String]): List[String] = {
    println("Inside the loop!" + pageNumber)

    val thisUrl = url.concat(
      s"OWNER_MI_KEY&dataset_version=v1.1&pageNumber=$pageNumber&pageSize=$pageSize"
    )

    MakePostHttpRestCalls(thisUrl) match {
      case "" =>
        responses.reverse
      case apiResponse =>
        println("Got api response")
        println("apiResponse :" + apiResponse)
        val apiJson = parseApiResponse(apiResponse) //parses the json response
        println("apiJson :" + apiJson)

        loop(pageNumber + 1, apiJson +: responses)
    }
  }

  loop(1, Nil)
}

val responsePages = readResponsePages(1000)
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same line because I noticed I would write many if statements with repeating logic. Quick question will this be able to get all the results from a single page before moving to the next? Also, what does reverse achieve in this case?

Comment: The `reverse` is an efficiency measure. It is faster to prepend to a `List` than append to it, so the main loop builds the `List` in reverse order and then reverses it at the end. (It is a standard trick for recursive list building)
Not sure of the details but the result should be a `List` of `apiJson` object, one for each page that was read.

Comment: I am getting a type mismatch  found List[java.io.Serializable ]  required List[String] at 
```
loop(pageNumber + 1, apiJson +: responses)
```

Comment: It's just rough code. I don't know what `parseApiResponse` returns but that should be the type of the `List` that is passed to and returned by `loop`

Comment: makes sense, let probe inside the parseApiResponse function further